# Symfony2 detach entity with ManyToOne association

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1, cascade

**Background:**

In my application I have an entity that has a **self referencing** `ManyToOne` association *(many children can point to a single parent)*. And I have a feature that does mass updates on many entities at one time using the Doctrine ORM. To keep performance from dropping dramatically due to many entities being loaded I `detach` entities once they've been updated.

**Problem:**

When I `detach` an entity that has *children* and later try to update any of those *children* Doctrine complains that it doesn't know the *parent* anymore. Even if I `merge` the *parent* entity before trying to update the *child*.

**Question:**

What am I doing wrong when I detach the *parent* entity? I've tried doing cascade="merge" and/or "detach" on the parent column and Doctrine still complains about the *parent* being an unknown entity when I try to persist.

I've mocked up a simple example that reproduces this. See below.

**Test Code:**

**Entity\Thing.php**

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Table(name="things")
 */
class Thing
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Thing", inversedBy="children", cascade={"detach","merge"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parentId", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="SET NULL")
     */
    protected $parent;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Thing", mappedBy="parent")
     */
    protected $children;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
     */
    protected $name;

    public function __construct($name = null)
    {
        $this->children = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    // .. SNIP ...
}
```

**Test Action:**

```php
public function testThingAction($_route)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $repo = $em->getRepository('AcmeThingBundle:Thing');

    // simple setup of a couple things in the DB
    $t1 = $repo->findByName('Thing1');
    if (!$t1) {
        $t1 = new Thing('Thing1');
        $t2 = new Thing('Thing2');
        $t2->setParent($t1);

        $em->persist($t1);
        $em->persist($t2);
        $em->flush();
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl($_route));
    }

    list($t1, $t2) = $repo->findAll();

    // detach and re-merge Thing1
    // This should cause Thing1 to be removed and then re-added 
    // to the doctrine's known entities; but it doesn't!?
    $em->detach($t1);
    $em->merge($t1);

    // try to update T2
    $t2->setName('Thing2 - ' . time());
    $em->persist($t2);
    // will fail with: 
    // A new entity was found through the relationship Thing#parent
    $em->flush();

    return array();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the child has a relationship to a specific parent object that is no longer managed by Doctrine. When you call `$entityManager->merge($entity)` you get a new managed entity back from that function.

When you get that back, you need to manually call `setParent()` on each of your children with the newly managed entity.

Comment: You're right about `merge` returning a new object (normally I don't need to re-merge entities; I just did that in my test). However, I see this as a potential flaw in Doctrine. Because once I detach the parent I can no longer persist any changes to any children. Anyone have any insight as to why this is intended behavior?

Comment: I wouldn't call it a flaw in doctrine. You're asking it to persist a child to a parent it doesn't know about. As far as doctrine is concerned, doing that will violate the foreign key constraint in your table (since it can't confirm that the entity is valid anymore). I think there are other optimizations you should worry about than detaching all of these entities. Like, for example, explicitly passing the entity you want to save to the `flush()` method so doctrine doesn't scan them all.

Comment: Well, that does make sense and has made me realize that I was focusing on the wrong entity to re-merge. Instead of trying to merge `$t1` I can merge `$t2` which can cascade to the parent. I've confirmed this works. Thanks for the input. I don't really use a lot of cascades, and I've tried all manner of other optimizations but detaching is the only way I've found to make my import feature work w/o slowing down to 1 persist per second or even slower.